# How to delete a destination telegram message if the source message is deleted

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I am creating a python program using Telethon to find a way to delete a message in the destination channel once the source message is deleted.

For eg:
A -- source channel
B -- destination channel

A posts a message X which gets forwarded to destination channel B. After sometime, A deletes message X, B should also delete that message.

My code looks like this:

```
@client.on(events.MessageDeleted)
async def edit_message_bot(event):
    ...
```

But the problem is when I use this method, msg_id from event is different for source and destination channel and hence couldn't find a way to delete it.

Please help

Comment: do also "Note that this event isn’t 100% reliable, since Telegram doesn’t always notify the clients that a message was deleted". as mentioned over [the docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/events.html#telethon.events.messagedeleted.MessageDeleted)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [source code](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/3d32e16235b0003c01bf73c75530a09d51926ec9/telethon/events/messagedeleted.py) for the `MessageDeleted` event and the documentation says:

> Telegram **does not** send information about *where* a message
> was deleted if it occurs in private conversations with other users
> or in small group chats, because message IDs are *unique* and you
> can identify the chat with the message ID alone if you saved it
> previously.
>
> Telethon **does not** save information of where messages occur,
> so it cannot know in which chat a message was deleted (this will
> only work in channels, where the channel ID *is* present).
>
> This means that the `chats=` parameter will not work reliably,
> unless you intend on working with channels and super-groups only.

In your case, you should get `chats` parameter, which can help. Also, you should use `deleted_ids`, not `msg_id`. [Link](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/quick-references/events-reference.html#messagedeleted)

I think you should store the message-id of the original message and id of the message in the destination channel so you can easily find it. So you'll have something like a dictionary where the original id and a new one are stored together.

Comment: "_...you should get `chats` parameter..._".    `chats` is a parameter to be set (as a filter) - not something to get from the event. (you mean `chat_id` ?)

Comment: sorry, documentation said `chats`, so I thought that's where you can get the chat id